# ESlint enforce closing brackets for functions etc on same column as opening

Tags: javascript, coding-style, eslint

How can I enforce closing brackets/parentheses for functions etc, on the same column in which the opening parenthesis occurs

E.g

```
// throws error
app.get('/', function (req, response) {

 }); // bracket/parentheses is *not on same* column as opening


// this is valid
app.get('/', function (req, response) {

}); // bracket/parentheses is on *same* column as opening
```

Comment: You probably mean "the same column as the *line in which* the opening parenthesis occurs"

Answer (score 0):

The [indent rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) covers what you're looking for, though it make be overkill if this one case is all you want to check. Try pasting the following into the [online demo](http://eslint.org/demo/) to see the error it gives:

```
/* eslint indent: 2 */

// throws error
app.get('/', function (req, response) {

 }); // bracket/parentheses is *not on same* column as opening


// this is valid
app.get('/', function (req, response) {

}); // bracket/parentheses is on *same* column as opening
```

The important part is the `/* eslint indent: 2 */` comment at the beginning. It enables the indent rule with the default settings, which happen to be four spaces, though the rule is configurable.

Comment: I already have `indent:2`. Unfortunately it doesn't deal with closing brackets though hence the question :)

Comment: What is the output of `eslint --version`? Try pasting my example on the demo - you'll get a warning for the mis-aligned bracket.

Comment: @btmills the `intend: 2` rule will still pass the case when you put 2*x tabs/ spaces before the closing brace

Comment: @StefanosChrs I'm getting an error for anything other than exactly 0 spaces before the closing brace. Can you paste something that's reproducible in the demo (eslint.org/demo)?

Comment: @StefanosChrs thanks, I can repro that. It's interesting that swapping the tab for spaces fails correctly. It looks like when indent is configured for spaces, it ignores tab-indented closing braces, and when it's configured for tabs, it ignores space-indented closing braces.

Comment: @btmills yes it's very strange, I've trying some time ago to find a solution for this but couldn't find anything